# RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, web

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

http://example.com/real-estate/?group=rentals
needs to go to 
http://example.com/real-estate/rentals

Here's what I have in my .htaccess that isn't working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/real-estate/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^group=rentals
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/real-estate/rentals/? [NC,R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This is very unusual... Typically people want the redirection the other way around. So your incoming http request really is to `http://example.com/real-estate/?group=rentals` and the visible URL should be changed to `http://example.com/real-estate/rentals`? _Really?_

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: RewriteCond does partial matches, have you tried without `^`? Also why do you place another `?` in the RewriteRule?

Answer (score 0):

This is very unusual... Typically people want the redirection the other way around....

Your code looks nearly fine, only some minor corrections. But those might be what you are missing:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/real-estate/?$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^group=rentals$
  RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/real-estate/rentals [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

For this to work the rules have to either be placed directly inside the http hosts configuration, or inside a `.htaccess` style file in the hosts document root with enabled interpretation of such files.

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: @chrislovessushi "didn't work" does not help, you will have to add more details to that statement. What happens? What do you see? What are the entries in your http servers error log file? Is the interpretation of `.htaccess` style files _really_ configured?

Comment: I added the above code (changing the example.com of course) to my .htaccess file in the root directory of my site. When I visit example.com/real-estate/?group=rentals it loads the page normally. I need the URL to change to example.com/real-estate/rentals

Comment: Then either you loaded the page from a previously cached version and need to clear your browsers cache once (or make a deep reload), or the interpretation of `.htaccess` style files is _not_ enabled inside our http host. Have a try placing a definite syntax error in the file and monitor your http servers error log file. What happens?

Comment: Yes, I added a line of garbage to htaccess and received a 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^real-estate/([^/]*)$ /real-estate/?group=$1 [L]
```

It will leave you with the URL: `http://example.com/real-estate/rentals`. Make sure you clear your cache before you test this.

Comment: I made sure to clear the cache but the URL is still displaying as example.com/real-estate/?group=rentals can you think of any reason why this would be the case?

Comment: What else do you have in your `.htaccess` file? As the above should work without issue.